# To remove characters in python

Tags: python

How can i remove character after FORTH     '.' ?

For eg 123.1223.123.123

I want the output as 123.1223.123

```
   x = "207.185.152.69.2005"
   y = 0
   for i in x:
     if (i == '.'):
        y = y + 1
           if (y == 4):
               i.replace('.','')
```

Comment: `print(x[:x.rfind('.')])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most optimized way to do this is

```
x = "207.185.152.69.2005"
print(x[:x.rfind('.')])
```

This method basically remove last occurrence. rfind look for last occurrence position and slice away all characters after that position.

Agreed with depperm commant, Thanx to depperm

Comment: Can you explain me this x[:x.rfind('.')] ?

Comment: _"Most optimized way to do this"_ - Well that all depends on the length of the string. In fact, this method will fail for strings with more than five dots. Not to take away from your answer, but I think using regex would be the more robust solution here.

Comment: @ChristianDean for this example string split/join method is twice as fast  as regexp; for a string created this way: `".".join(["g" * 10000] *10)` it is the other way 'round.

Comment: it doesnot print the last num if i do print(x[:x.rfind('!')]) . Instead of returning entire string , it misses out the last num

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regular expression that will only match what you want:

```
\d*\.\d*\.\d*
```

Here is some python code that will do this:

```
# IMPORT
import re

# SET UP REGEX
myre = re.compile(r"\d*\.\d*\.\d*")

# FIND MATCH
matches = myre.findall(dataString)

# PRINTS STRING YOUR LOOKING FOR
print(matches[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Split,slice and join
".".join((x.split(".")[:4]))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see 'Help' at the top right of the answer window to see how to format code.  Also, it may help if you explain your answer some. What was the problem with the OP's code? How does this fix it?